# Can I use the sentence as this: " I tuned into Netflix to watch the movie "

Tags: grammaticality

Or is it rather " I tuned in to Netflix to watch some movies"

Comment: "To tune into something" (with its literal meaning) seems old-fashioned to me.

Comment: I agree. Modern American usage would say 'I watched a movie on Netflix last night'. Or even to verbize it as 'I Netflixed last night'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your question is about the difference between *in* and *into.* As others have said, *tuned* may or may not be the best choice for the sentence, but we'll leave that aside. (I think *tuned* is OK, albeit a bit unusual.)

In this case, use *in to* because we use *tune* + *in* to mean adjust to the correct frequency: "I *tuned in* too late to hear the end of the basketball game." On old-time radio, announcers said, "*Tune in* next time to hear more exciting adventures ..."

Generally, save *into* when you're talking about movement or direction, whether physical or metaphorical. (She walked *into* the restaurant. Dracula turned *into* a bat.)

Answer (score 0):

"Tuning" comes from adjusting a dial to match the frequency of a radio or television stream — it's become a bit idiomatic in the same way that "hanging up" and "dialing" a phone are no longer literal descriptions.

[See the specific definition for "tuning in" here.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tune-in)

You can still say "tuning" when switching between channels on a set top box (for cable television) because it approximates the experience of selecting live channels in the older, analog way.

Netflix, whether used as a website or an application, doesn't mimic that experience, especially because it does not offer live content. You can "tune into" a Twitch stream, but not a Youtube video.

For Netflix, depending on the situation, you could say "I opened Netflix to watch the movie," "I launched Netflix..." "I went to Netflix.." or "I logged onto Netflix..."

Comment: That doesn't quite answer her question, which is about choosing between the prepositions *in* and *into*.

Comment: I interpreted the overall question as being whether "tuned into" is a correct verbal phrase for Nissa's intended meaning — with her body copy offering a guess for a possible correct answer. My response addresses the main question: whether it is proper to use that sentence.

If others agree that my response doesn't answer the spirit of her question, I'm happy to revise or revoke.

Comment: I agree that the question itself is unclear as to what is being asked.

Answer (score -2):

It depends, did you watch A movie? Or several movies? That seems to be the crux of your question and the answer relies entirely on number of films viewed.

Comment: I don't think that answers her question, which is about choosing the most apt preposition, *in* or *into*.

Comment: That does seem more likely. I mistook the nature of what was being asked, although in my defense, it is a bit unclear as the number of films changed between the two examples.